# In HTML, how do I append variables to urls?

Tags: html

I have a list of addresses in a table and I want it so that if you click on the address, you get a Google Maps link to that place. Here is my attempt; the <a ...> is my attempt at getting it but ultimately failing. I want a sample google maps page to take you to https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=40%2C-70 if (40,-70) was the lat/long so that it actually shows the latitude/longitude described in the fields.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Address</th>
  <th>Zip Code</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
  {% for pl in markers %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{pl.fields.name}}</td>
    <td><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query="pl.fields.latitude"%2C"pl.fields.longitude">{{pl.fields.address}}</a></td>
    <td>{{pl.fields.zip}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Here is what is outputted:

[image]

The links should direct to the google maps API for the latitude/longitude, but right now it doesn't work. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: why not `...search/?api=1&query="{{pl.fields.latitude}}%2C{{pl.fields.longitude}}>`

Comment: that only gives "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" without the latitude/longitude

Answer (score 1):

The extra quotes are throwing it off.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Address</th>
  <th>Zip Code</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
  {% for pl in markers %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{pl.fields.name}}</td>
<td><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query={{pl.fields.latitude}},{{pl.fields.longitude}}">{{pl.fields.address}}</a></td>
    <td>{{pl.fields.zip}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: I set my latitude/longitude as latitude/longitude, not lat/lng.

Comment: Did this answer update help (fixed quotes)? Did you get it solved?